# HowTo restore Grafana dashboard on a new/different computer

Tags: grafana, dashboard, restore

I did an export on my old machine. Than on the new machine an import. The Database names are the same. I'm using influx.

Dashboard is visible, but no data. If I use 'edit'  on a panel and click on the based database, I get the data. It's a lot of work, but it works. The problem is Mixed mode (using data from diffenent datasource in the query). There I get the error:

> Data source plugin does not export any Query Editor component

And it is difficult to restore the original. I have to choose one of the used databases. Than all queries will use this. Than I have to delete the query with other database and make a new one.

1. Is there a way to import as dashboard to a new machine with autoupdate/refresh the database/datasources?
2. Is there a way - as workaround - to change a database of a single query in a panel (I'm only able to change database for the whole panel, not for a single query, if I'm in mixed mode)?
3. What does the error message mean? Perhaps the main problem?

Or did I something wrong in my process?
Thanks

Comment: What Grafana versions are you using on your old and new computer?

Comment: new one is 7.3.6; the old computer had 7.2.2. It's installed on a Raspi

Comment: That difference does not look that much. Probably the datasourches are named differently, maybe rename the datasource on the new one and resname them after the import.

Comment: It'doesn't work. I now find a usable way. In the non mixe panels I changed the datasource back and forward. In mixed databases I used the "pencil"  to get the SQL code and changed the FROM-clause from <fieldname>  to <sourceName fieldname>.

Some work, but it works now :-)

Thanks vor replying